# Qt 5.7 dock widget as child of another widget

Tags: qt, qt5, qt-designer, qdockwidget

With Qt 5.7 Designer, is it possible to have dock widget as child of another widget, e.g. within tab widget (which is within stacked widget)?

Comment: As far as I know can dock widgets only be added to a QMainWindow.

Comment: True in the designer. Not sure, with hand-coding.

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to do this because a `QDockWidget` must be docked inside a `QMainWindow`, and Qt Designer does not allow a `QMainWindow` to be added as a child widget.

However, in hand-written code, `QMainWindow` can be treated just like any other widget and so, as per your example, it could be set as a page inside a `QTabWidget`. Any dock-widgets added to that page would then behave just the same as they would in a top-level main-window.